# Conditional operators on css values using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am trying this:

```
if($("#img").css("left")>=100)
```

but it always returns false because `$("#img").css("left")` returns `"200px"` as a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`parseInt` will convert the string into an integer for you:

```
if(parseInt($("#img").css("left"), 10)>=100)
```

Comment: In case anyone was wondering, the second parameter is to define which numeral system to use, in that case base 10 numerals.

Comment: @MohamedKhamis Correct. Not sure that `$("#img").css("left")` would ever return prefixed numbers, but better safe than sorry :)

Comment: @RGraham better you add the explanation. Anyway I already +1 this

Answer (score 1):

A temporary solution is to use this function that returns the value of the css attribute, excluding the `"px"`:

```
function getCSSval(str){
    return parseInt(str.substring(0, str.length - 2));
    //e.g. "200px" --> "200"
}
```

But I was hoping there could be a more straight forward way

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse the returned value to an integer to compare it with `100`:

`if (parseInt($("#img").css("left"), 10) >= 100)`

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient code to get the integer part is the use of `regular expressions`

```
if(parseInt($("#img").css("left").replace(/\s?px/i, "")) >= 100)
```